PGF for Functions of Random Variables
These are some well known properties/formulas for Expectations:

For a continuous random variable $X$ with probability density function (pdf) $f(x)$, the expected value (or mean) of $X$ is given by:

$$ E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) \, dx $$

If $G(x)$ is a function of $X$, then the expected value of $G(X)$ is given by:

$$ E(G(X)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(x) f(x) \, dx $$

And here is the change of variable rule that gives the actual pdf for the transformed random variable:

$$ h(y) = f(G^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{d}{dy} G^{-1}(y) \right| $$
I was wondering if similar formulas exist for Probability Generating Functions.
For example, I know that for linear sums of random variables (e.g. PGF of $X$ + $Y$), the following property generally holds (provided they are independent of each other):
$$ \begin{aligned}
G_{f(X,Y)}(s) &= E[s^{X+Y}] \\
&= E[s^X \cdot s^Y] \\
&= E[s^X] \cdot E[s^Y] \quad \text{(assuming X and Y are independent)} \\
&= G_X(s) \cdot G_Y(s)
\end{aligned} $$
$$ G_{X+Y}(s) = G_X(s) \cdot G_Y(s) $$
Can this property be generalized for any function of $X$, $Y$?
$$ G_{f(X,Y)}(s) = E[s^{f(X,Y)}]$$
As an example, I tried to take the PGF for the exponent of 2 random variables:
$$ G_{X_1^{X_2}}(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^{X_1^{X_2}}] $$
In general, the probability-generating function (PGF) for $ X $ is given by:
$$
G_X(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^X]
$$
Use the law of total expectation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) to condition on one of the variables, we can condition on $ X_2 $ and use the law of total expectation:
$$
G_{X_1^{X_2}}(s) = \mathbb{E}[s^{X_1^{X_2}}] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[s^{X_1^{X_2}} \mid X_2]]
$$
Now, we evaluate the inner expectation by conditioning on $ X_2 = k $:
$$
\mathbb{E}[s^{X_1^{X_2}} \mid X_2 = k] = \mathbb{E}[s^{X_1^k}]
$$
Since $ s^{X_1^k} = (s^k)^{X_1} $, we can write:
$$
\mathbb{E}[s^{X_1^k}] = (s^k)^{X_1} \cdot \mathbb{E}[s^{X_1}]
$$
Therefore, the inner expectation becomes:
$$
\mathbb{E}[s^{X_1^{X_2}} \mid X_2] = (s^{X_2})^{X_1} \cdot \mathbb{E}[s^{X_1}]
$$
Now, we take the outer expectation:
$$
G_{X_1^{X_2}}(s) = \mathbb{E}[(s^{X_2})^{X_1} \cdot \mathbb{E}[s^{X_1}]]
$$
Since $ \mathbb{E}[s^{X_1}] $ is a constant with respect to $ X_2 $, we can factor it out:
$$
G_{X_1^{X_2}}(s) = \mathbb{E}[(s^{X_2})^{X_1}] \cdot \mathbb{E}[s^{X_1}]
$$
Finally, we can express this as a sum over the possible values of $ X_2 $:
$$
G_{X_1^{X_2}}(s) = \sum_{k} \mathbb{E}[(s^k)^{X_1}] \cdot P(X_2 = k)
$$

For some reason, you went from considering $\mathbb E[s^{X_1^{X_2}}]$ to $\mathbb E[s^{X_1 + X_2}]$, and you already addressed the latter case under the condition that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, so I don't quite understand your intent here.
Note that when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent, the law of total expectation yields
$$\mathbb E[s^{X_1 + X_2}] = \mathbb E[ \mathbb E[s^{X_1 + X_2} \mid X_2]] = \mathbb E[s^{X_2} \mathbb E[s^{X_1} \mid X_2]],$$ but from this point you cannot proceed further, because without independence, you cannot conclude
$$\mathbb E[s^{X_1} \mid X_2] = \mathbb E[s^{X_1}].$$
For instance, $\mathbb E[X_1 \mid X_2]$ under the hierarchical model
$$X_2 \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p), \\ X_1 \mid X_2 \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(X_2 + 1),$$
gives us
$$\mathbb E[X_1 \mid X_2] = X_2 + 1,$$
but
$$\mathbb E[X_1] = p+1.$$
This is why the PGF of the sum of two random variables $X_1 + X_2$ equals the product of the individual PGFs only if they are independent.
Next, if we are to discuss a quantity such as $$\mathbb E[s^{X_1^{X_2}}],$$ you would have similar issues with independence.  So if we assume they are in fact independent,
$$\mathbb E[s^{X_1^{X_2}}] = \mathbb E[ \mathbb E[s^{X_1^{X_2}} \mid X_2]]$$
and again, we cannot proceed further.  The conditional expectation given $X_2$ is the PGF of the transformed random variable $X_1^{X_2}$ for a fixed $X_2$.
There are certain functions of $X_1, X_2$ that allow a factorization of PGFs under the independence condition; of course, addition is one such example.  But we also have the general linear combination $$f(X_1, X_2) = aX_1 + bX_2$$ which, for fixed $a, b$ and independence, implies
$$G_{aX_1 + bX_2}(s) = G_{X_1}(s^a) G_{X_2}(s^b).$$

@ heropup: sorry, I have now fixed the latex

@ heropup: based on these corrections - was my initial analysis of the exponents on the right track?

@wulasa No, because in general, $a^{b^c} \ne (a^c)^b$.

@ heropup: thank you. so in general - when it comes to functions of random variables, there is no generic formula for the PGF ?

@ heropup: I tried to attempt this question ... can you please take a look at it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4957479/number-of-coin-flips-before-a-certain-condition-is-reached
